# Dummy mail server

Tags: email, debug, web-development

In my development PC I want to see all mail sent using PHP `mail()` function. Is there any dummy mail server that could show all sent mail (regardless of their recipient) and collect them in a mail box to preview?

Comment: See [How to develop and test an app that sends emails?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1006650/309483)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go: [smtp4dev](http://smtp4dev.codeplex.com/)

> Windows 7/Vista/XP/2003/2010 compatible dummy SMTP server. Sits in the system tray and does not deliver the received messages. The received messages can be quickly viewed, saved and the source/structure inspected. Useful for testing/debugging software that generates email.

Answer (score 0):

phi's solution is great if you have a Windows environment.

If you have a Linux environment - then you can setup postfix to deliver all email to a local mailbox.

Here is a link to get you started - https://serverfault.com/questions/144325/how-to-redirect-all-postfix-emails-to-one-external-email-address

```
Create /etc/postfix/virtual-regexp with the following content:

/.+@.+/ email@gmail.com
Edit /etc/postfix/main.cf and add regexp:/etc/postfix/virtual-regexp to the virtual_maps configuration. The end result might look like this in main.cf:

virtual_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual, regexp:/etc/postfix/virtual-regexp
Build the mapfile by typing:

postmap /etc/postfix/virtual-regexp
This also requires a virtual.db to exist. If it doesn't create an empty file called virtual and run : postmap /etc/postfix/virtual

Voila!
```